# Connection was reset when accessing magento admin panel

Tags: php, cookies, admin, magento-1.9

I got this error when second time login to the admin panel of magento ,

frontend works with no issue ,

[image]

Any help is appreciated , i disabled cookie in varien.php too like as follows

```
$cookieParams = array(
            'lifetime' => $cookie->getLifetime(),
            'path'     => $cookie->getPath(),
     //       'domain'   => $cookie->getConfigDomain(),
      //      'secure'   => $cookie->isSecure(),
       //     'httponly' => $cookie->getHttponly()
        );
//
//        if (!$cookieParams['httponly']) {
//            unset($cookieParams['httponly']);
//            if (!$cookieParams['secure']) {
//                unset($cookieParams['secure']);
//                if (!$cookieParams['domain']) {
//                    unset($cookieParams['domain']);
//                }
//            }
//        }
```

and i deleted domain cookies from firebug too .

Comment: why you disabled cookie in varien.php?

Comment: from search i found this : http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel

Comment: I saw it, as you can see, no need to change core file. check this the steps that Alan Storm said

Comment: Yea i removed the comments now , once i tried with my ip like 10.10.10.103/magento-1.9 , is that an issue ?? since firebug stores  2 cookies for adminhtml as localhost and 10.10.10.103 when taking the admin panel login

Comment: Check if you have permissions on /var/session if you save session in files, not in Redis

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/64704/discussion-between-icecreamsandwich-and-sergio).

Comment: I'm having a similiar issue, it might be related - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30998981/post-redirect-throws-a-connection-was-reset-browser-error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are can be a lot of [reasons](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/magento-1-9-can-t-login-to-admin-panel).

Ussualy clear cache (`project/var/cache`). Also clear browser coockies.

Check if you script has permissions to write a files into `var/session` or in `Redis` and so on.
(It depends how you configure your session storage in admin panel)

Answer (score 1):

In our case, this 'Connection Reset' issue happened when Magento tried to connect to the third party services. I saw the issue on the 'View Cart/Check Out' process, and by disabling default shipping methods includes UPS/DHL, it disappeared.
Similarly, you might want to disable Mage_Connect at the 'Configuration:Advanced' and see what would happen.

Answer (score 0):

Check php version, for latest Magento it must be `version 5.5`.